# Is there a way move data from a Delta Table in S3 to Redshift using Copy Command?

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-redshift, delta-lake

I've Delta Tables that are created in a S3 Bucket, need to load this data as-is into Redshift tables.
The delta table has Symlink Format Manifest generated and some delta tables might have partitions.
Is there a way to move this data into Redshift?

I've tried to run the Copy Command on the Delta Table giving the path till the Table Name.

```
COPY <schema>.<table>
FROM 's3://<bucket-name>/<delta_table_name>/'
IAM_ROLE '<iam_role>' 
FORMAT AS PARQUET
```

Tried to run the Copy Command using the path to the Symlink Format Manifest directory in S3. Neither worked.

```
COPY <schema>.<table>
FROM 's3://<bucket-name>/<delta_table_name>/_symlink_format_manifest/PARTITION1=VALUE1/PARTITION2=VALUE2/manifest'
IAM_ROLE '<iam_role>' 
FORMAT AS PARQUET
```

Comment: Looks as if Delta Lake is supported with `EXTERNAL TABLE`, see https://docs.delta.io/latest/redshift-spectrum-integration.html Then you could select from the table.

Comment: @MP24 We need to move the data into the Redshift Table, not an external table. Anyway to move that?

Comment: You can then select from the external table into your target tables.

Comment: What about performance? I'm assuming it won't be as performant as COPY?

Comment: From my experience (with Parquet files), external tables and copy are equally fast.